# Mocking a Static Method without replayAll() in PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

Does anyone know of a way to do a mock of a static class without calling replayAll()?  I've seen many examples where people mock the Math.random() and use the replayAll().  To me it seems like replayAll() is the lazier way to go about things, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to use the replay(Object mocks) to mock static methods.

For example consider the following example I found on 
[PowerMockTutorial](http://www.thedance.net/~roth/TECHBLOG/powerMock.html):

```
public class Dice {
   public int sumOfNumDieRolls (int num) { 
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i=0;   i<num;   ++i) {
         int roll = (int) (6. * Math.random()) + 1;
         sum += roll;
      }
      return sum;
   }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {Dice.class} )
public class DiceTest {
   @Test
   public void shouldAddUpDieRollsCorrectly() {
      PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Math.class, "random");
      EasyMock.expect (Math.random()).andReturn(0.3334).anyTimes();
      Dice die = new Dice();
      PowerMock.replayAll();
      assertEquals (12, die.sumOfNumDieRolls(4));
      assertEquals (30, die.sumOfNumDieRolls(10));
      PowerMock.verifyAll();
   }
}
```

I'm using PowerMock version 1.4.10.

Comment: Apparently you can do a `PowerMock.verify(Math.class);` which should work.

Comment: PowerMock.replay(Math.class) is working for me with the very same code, I only changed this line and the version to 1.4.10.
EDIT: PowerMock.verify(Math.class) is also working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do do this by using the PowerMock.replay([object_name]) so that you don't have to do the replay all.  For this example it would look like the following:

```
public class Dice {
   public int sumOfNumDieRolls (int num) { 
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i=0;   i<num;   ++i) {
         int roll = (int) (6. * Math.random()) + 1;
         sum += roll;
      }
      return sum;
   }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {Dice.class} )
public class DiceTest {
   @Test
   public void shouldAddUpDieRollsCorrectly() {
      PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Math.class, "random");
      EasyMock.expect (Math.random()).andReturn(0.3334).anyTimes();
      Dice die = new Dice();
      PowerMock.replay(Math.class);
      assertEquals (12, die.sumOfNumDieRolls(4));
      assertEquals (30, die.sumOfNumDieRolls(10));
      PowerMock.verify(Math.class);
   }
}
```